# Trivial functors

Tags: python, python-3.x, functor

I very often write code like:

```
sorted(some_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda x: x['age'])
map(lambda x: x.name, rows)
```

where I would like to write:

```
sorted(some_dict.items(), key=idx_f(1))
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=idx_f('name'))
map(attr_f('name'), rows)
```

using:

```
def attr_f(field):
  return lambda x: getattr(x, field)

def idx_f(field):
  return lambda x: x[field]
```

Are there functor-creators like idx_f and attr_f in python, and are they of clearer when used than lambda's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `operator` module has [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) and [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) that do just that:

```
from operator import attrgetter, itemgetter

sorted(some_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=itemgetter('name'))
map(attrgetter('name'), rows)
```

These functions also take *more than one* argument, at which point they'll return a tuple containing the value for each argument:

```
# sorting on value first, then on key
sorted(some_dict.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0))

# sort dictionaries by last name, then first name
sorted(list_of_dicts, key=itemgetter('last_name', 'first_name'))
```

The `attrgetter()` function also accepts *dotted names*, where you can reach attributes of attributes:

```
# extract contact names
map(attrgetter('contact.name'), companies)
```

Comment: great! I remember using these way back, but couldn't find them on Google.